# Passing viewdatadictionary to partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

I have partial view call in my application:

```
<div id="Pozicije"> @Html.Partial("_Pozicije", Model.pozicije, null)</div>
```

that works. I have changed it to:

```
<div id="Pozicije"> @Html.Partial("_Pozicije", Model.pozicije, new ViewDataDictionary { { "Pozicije", true } })</div>
```

And this is not working, because model become null and partial view won't load.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive this is becuase your model property name matches the view data item key value. They are both `pozicije`. Try another key value for view data dictionary. 
I used to have similar problem and fixed that by changing view data key value.

Hope it helps!